# Caching with retrofit 2.0 and rxjava 2 with okhttp3

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm trying to perform offline cashing when internet connection is lost so that i can display data from cache . here is what I've done till now .
my question is how can make my observable return the cached arraylist of data instead of just returning error?
my service generator :

```
public class ServiceGenerator {

public static final String API_BASE_URL = UrlManager.BASE_URL_API;
private static final String CACHE_CONTROL = "Cache-Control";



private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()

private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()));
private static Retrofit retrofit;

public static Gson getGson() {
    return gson;
}

public static void setup() {

    httpClient.addInterceptor(provideOfflineCacheInterceptor());
    httpClient.addInterceptor(new AddCookiesInterceptor()); // VERY VERY IMPORTANT
    httpClient.addInterceptor(new ReceivedCookiesInterceptor()); // VERY VERY IMPORTANT
    httpClient.addInterceptor( provideHttpLoggingInterceptor() );
    httpClient.addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor());// Stetho
    httpClient.addNetworkInterceptor(provideCacheInterceptor());
    httpClient.cache(provideCache());
    OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
    retrofit = builder.client(client).build();
}

public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
    return createService(serviceClass, null);
}

public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, final String authToken) {
    if (authToken != null) {
        httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request original = chain.request();

                // Request customization: add request headers
                Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                        .header("Authorization", authToken)
                        .method(original.method(), original.body());

                Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });
    }


    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
}

public static Interceptor provideCacheInterceptor() {
    return new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());

            // re-write response header to force use of cache
            CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl.Builder()
                    .maxAge(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .build();

            return response.newBuilder()
                    .header(CACHE_CONTROL, cacheControl.toString())
                    .build();
        }
    };
}

public static Interceptor provideOfflineCacheInterceptor() {
    return new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();

            if (!UruzApplication.hasNetwork()) {
                CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl.Builder()
                        .maxStale(7, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                        .build();

                request = request.newBuilder()
                        .cacheControl(cacheControl)
                        .build();
            }

            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    };
}

private static Cache provideCache() {
    Cache cache = null;
    try {
        cache = new Cache(new File(UruzApplication.getInstance().getCacheDir(), "http-cache"),
                10 * 1024 * 1024); // 10 MB
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Timber.e(e, "Could not create Cache!");
    }
    return cache;
}
private static HttpLoggingInterceptor provideHttpLoggingInterceptor ()
{
    HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor =
            new HttpLoggingInterceptor( new HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger()
            {
                @Override
                public void log (String message)
                {
                    Timber.d( message );
                }
            } );
    httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel( true ? HEADERS : NONE );
    return httpLoggingInterceptor;
}
```

}

my observer :

```
 public static Observable<List<WeekDietPlan>>
fetchPackageWeeksDaysDietPlan(int traineeId) {

    DietService requestService = ServiceGenerator.createService(DietService.class);
    return requestService.getPackageWeekDaysDietPlan(UrlManager.getTraineeDietPackageDetailsUrl(),
            traineeId)
            .flatMap(new Function<JsonElement, Observable<List<WeekDietPlan>>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<List<WeekDietPlan>> apply(JsonElement jsonElement) throws Exception {
                    JsonObject asJsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
                    String result = asJsonObject.get(UrlManager.ResultTypes.RESULT).getAsString();

                    Timber.d(TAG, "result Tag" + result);

                    if (UrlManager.ResultTypes.isError(result) || UrlManager.ResultTypes.isFailure(result)) {
                        String errorMessage = asJsonObject.get(UrlManager.ResultTypes.RESULT_ERROR_MESSAGE).getAsString();
                        return Observable.error(new Exception(errorMessage));
                    }


                    if (UrlManager.ResultTypes.isSucess(result)) {


                        if (!GsonHelper.isNull(asJsonObject.get(UrlManager.ResultTypes.RESULT_DATA)) && asJsonObject.get(UrlManager.ResultTypes.RESULT_DATA).isJsonArray()) {
                            return Observable.just(WeekDietPlan.PackageDietWeekDaysListParser.fromJsonElement(asJsonObject.getAsJsonArray(UrlManager.ResultTypes.RESULT_DATA)));
                        } else {
                            return Observable.error(new Exception("Data is empty"));
                        }


                    }

                    if (UrlManager.ResultTypes.isLogin(result)) {
                        return Observable.error(new SessionTimeoutException());
                    }


                    return Observable.error(new Exception("Unkown Tag"));
                }
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

}
```

my api call :

```
private void retrievePackageWeekDaysPlan() {
    hideConnectionErrorLayout();
    if (!swipRefreshLayout_reLoad.isRefreshing()) {
        swipRefreshLayout_reLoad.setRefreshing(true);
    }

    DietNetworkCall.fetchPackageWeeksDaysDietPlan(1).subscribe(new Observer<List<WeekDietPlan>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            Timber.d(TAG, "onSubscribe() called with: d = [" + d + "]");
            compositeSubscription.add(d);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(List<WeekDietPlan> list) {
            Timber.d(TAG, "onNext() called with: value = [" + list.size() + "]");
            swipRefreshLayout_reLoad.setRefreshing(false);

            hideConnectionErrorLayout();

            if (list.size() == 0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.noDietPackageAvailable, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            bindRecyclerData(list);


        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Timber.d(TAG, "onError() called with: e = [" + e + "]");

            swipRefreshLayout_reLoad.setRefreshing(false);
            if (e instanceof IOException) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.connectionError, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            } else if (e instanceof NullPointerException) {

            } else if (e instanceof SessionTimeoutException) {
                AuthenticationManager.logOut();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                        e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete() called");
        }
    });


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, and directed towards future folks.

There is a need to create a `Network Interceptor` like this

```
public abstract class NetworkConnectionInterceptor implements Interceptor {

public abstract boolean isInternetAvailable();

public abstract void onInternetUnavailable();

public abstract void onCacheUnavailable();

@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();
    if (!isInternetAvailable()) {
        onInternetUnavailable();
        request = request.newBuilder().header("Cache-Control",
                "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + 60 * 60 * 24).build();
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        if (response.cacheResponse() == null) {
            onCacheUnavailable();
        }
        return response;
    }
    return chain.proceed(request);
}
}
```

Then add it with your okhttp builder. You can refer to this [link](https://medium.com/@tsaha.cse/advanced-retrofit2-part-1-network-error-handling-response-caching-77483cf68620).

One more you should take care is to check your `response "Cache-control" header`. Its value has to be like this `"max-age=2592000"`.

Answer (score 0):

To return the cached data instead of the error, you could use the [onErrorReturn](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#onErrorReturn(rx.functions.Func1)) operator that:

> Instructs an Observable to emit an item (returned by a specified
>   function) rather than invoking onError if it encounters an error.

List of the different operators to recover on error: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators

Comment: yea but how can I return the cached data.

Comment: `onErrorReturn` take as parameter a function invoked when there is an error; the item returned by this function will be propagated by the `Observable` instead of the error. This operator enable to replace errors with valid response that you defined, in your case your cache data.

Comment: bro I totally understand this part , what i want is how can I get the cached data from retrofit.

Comment: Ok I focused on " how can make my observable return the cached arraylist of data instead of just returning error?", and didn't get it was about OkHttp3 configuration. My response stand for the case you want to handle cache yourself; at each successful call you store the value in a property, and use `onErrorReturn` with this property as a caching solution.